# How to pass an array to a Web API POST method that accepts both XML and JSON payloads?

Tags: json, xml, rest, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I have a small problem where I have built a WebAPI service endpoint that accepts an array object. I'm not sure if my DTO classes are constructed correctly or what I may be missing something, but the object is empty when I post as XML. I have integrated with Swagger and use the example structure to post data. See below code:

Models:

```
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Note[] Notes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Note
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult AddStudentRecord(Student[] student)
    {
        return Json(student);
    }
```

Request Object:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Students>
    <Student>
      <Name>John Doe</Name>
      <Age>13</Age>
      <Notes>
       <Note>
        <Content>Some Notes</Content>
        <CreatedDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z</CreatedDate>
       </Note>
      </Notes>
    </Student>
   </Students>
```

What is the correct way to configure my object in such a way it caters for both JSON and XML without this issue. The problem if I wrap the list in another class for example called Notes, now it messes up the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I need to wrap my request as follows, now data is coming through and I also include the follow in the webApiConfig.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfStudent>
   <Student>
      <Name>string</Name>
      <Age>1</Age>
      <Notes>
         <Note>
            <Content>string</Content>
            <CreatedDate>1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z</CreatedDate>
         </Note>
      </Notes>
   </Student>
</ArrayOfStudent>
```

WebAPIConfig:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```